# CoreText: Underline wrong position when skewing fonts

Tags: objective-c, core-text

Underline & italics works fine using NSAttributedStrings.

Now, if I have a font that doesn't have italic style installed, I use the NSObliquenessAttributeName which skews the font simulating the italics.

The problem is that the underline appears at the end of the skewed text.

[image: underlined text shows malpositioned]